# UPDATE date range into date columns if dates don't overlap with existing ones

Tags: sql, postgresql, validation, datetime

A follow up question to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30437434/6131477). Since I can't comment on the answer, I can't ask directly.

I need to update a row and still have it check whether times overlap with other entries. However, I don't know how I can change the statement to exclude looking at itself during the check.

With an Insert statement like this

```
INSERT INTO table (name, starttime, endtime) 
SELECT 'test', '2016-10-12 22:00:00', '2016-10-12 23:00:00'
FROM (SELECT 1) x 
LEFT 
JOIN table y 
ON y.starttime < '2016-10-12 23:00:00' AND y.endtime > '2016-10-12 22:00:00' 
WHERE y.id is NULL LIMIT 1;
```

How do I modify my UPDATE statement to do the same while excluding the row being updated from the check?

```
UPDATE table SET name = 'test2', starttime = '2016-10-12 22:15:00',
endtime = '2016-10-12 23:00:00'  WHERE id = 1
```

id is the primary key, and I'm using it to identify the row

Comment: Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL? You have both tagged.

Comment: Sorry about that, postgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists` in both `insert` and `update` queries:

```
insert into a_table (name, starttime, endtime) 
select 'test', '2016-10-12 22:00:00', '2016-10-12 23:00:00'
where not exists (
    select 1 from a_table
    where starttime < '2016-10-12 23:00:00' and endtime > '2016-10-12 22:00:00'
    );

update a_table 
set name = 'test2', starttime = '2016-10-12 22:15:00', endtime = '2016-10-12 23:00:00'  
where id = 1 
and not exists (
    select 1 from a_table
    where id <> 1 
    and starttime < '2016-10-12 23:00:00' and endtime > '2016-10-12 22:15:00'
    );
```

Comment: Both work flawlessly! Thanks for your help. SQL syntax is rather new to me.